# Running Windows Forms and ASP.NET Core Web API together in .NET 6

Tags: winforms, asp.net-core, architecture, .net-6.0, background-processing

I'm using .NET 6.

[Solution View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAXWf.png)

As seen in the diagram, I'm using a certain architecture. My application connects to SQL from both a project named IBKS 2.0 (Windows Forms) and IBKSWebAPI (ASP.NET Core Web API) projects, and performs operations.

If I create a setup for the IBKS 2.0 project, will the Web API run in the background? Currently, when I run the IBKS 2.0 project through Visual Studio, the Web API also runs in the background.

If it doesn't work, what could be a possible solution?

I'm open to all kinds of comments and suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure if you are looking for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2022).